# JPA + Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a small project based on Spring MVC + JPA + MYSQL. for some reasons I need to have my several entities Audited. I searched a bit and found that @Audited -- anotation does it for me.

1. My Question is is this a good way to go for Auditing entities from Hibernate while using JPA for all the rest. Is there same functionality in JPA?
2. Finally I need to get audited REVISION right after inserting it into DB - Before commit actually - for this reason I found    @transactioneventlistener - but I don't know why it is not working for me - can JPA configuration miss thinks up?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) You can use [Auditing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.DATAJPA-580-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/auditing.html) from Spring Data, but if you are not dependent to it, DO NOT USE IT just for 2 annotations, prefer to use Hibernate.

Comment: 2) JPA has [PrePersist](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PrePersist.html) to handle entity lifecycle.

Comment: @BogdanOros - how can I use that to get revision ID of Audited entity? can you please give me code example?

Comment: An example of `@PrePersist`?

Comment: Example of getting Revision while @PrePersist

Comment: Hmm, problem is that you can't handle all audited entities by default, you need to have an interface `Auditable` to specify the method input parameter.

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you try to achieve. What does Audited means for you?

Comment: Let say I have Entity Cat - that is marked as @Audited -- and I need to get REV number before commit for table Cat_AUD -- that is automatically generated by Hibernate

Answer (score 2):

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingListener.class)
class SomeAuditedEntity { ... }

class AuditingListener {

    @PrePersist
    void preHandle(Object auditableObject) {
    }
}
```

`Object` is not the best way to handle lifecycle, prefer to use some custom interface like `Auditable`

Comment: I already use  that on my entity     ' @PrePersist
    void updateCreatedDate() {
        this.creationDate = new Date();
    } '   --- what I need is to get REV ID of _AUD table. how can I do that

Comment: Let say I have Entity Cat - that is marked as @Audited -- and I need to get REV number before commit for table Cat_AUD -- that is automatically generated by Hibernate

Comment: You can use `AuditReader` to create a query and create a query to fetch all entity revisions you need.

Comment: I have created Listener - and now I'm getting my Entity (Cat entity for example) on @PrePersist - but the problem is that I don't know how to get the _AUD object on PrePersist (Cat_AUD for example). I need to get number of Revision - that was generated by Hibernate. How can I do that?

Comment: AuditReader reads from database already persisted items - I need to get the Revision ID before Audited entity gets persisted to database. I wasn't able to get the Revision Number from AuditReader before commit - if it is possible please give me an example.

Comment: [EntityTrackingRevisionListener](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/EntityTrackingRevisionListener.html) interface receives all possible information you can receive and executes before entity commiting.